# How to display a message while searching within an ASPX page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a search in my ASPX page which once clicked displays a result using UpdatePanel, so it's displaying the result without page refresh. The function that does the search is here:

```
public void onBtnClick() { 
        Conn = new SqlConnection(cString); 
        Conn.Open(); 

        theGender = slcGender.SelectedItem.Text; 

        if (slcLocation.SelectedItem.Value == "") { 
            locVal = slcLocation.SelectedItem.Value; 
            lVal = "All Locations"; 
        } 
        if (slcLocation.SelectedItem.Value != "") { 
            locVal = slcLocation.SelectedItem.Text; 
            lVal = slcLocation.SelectedItem.Text; 
        } 
        if (slcSpecialty.SelectedItem.Value == "") { 
            speVal = slcSpecialty.SelectedItem.Value; 
            sVal = "All Specialties"; 
        } 
        if (slcSpecialty.SelectedItem.Value != "") { 
            speVal = slcSpecialty.SelectedItem.Text; 
            sVal = slcSpecialty.SelectedItem.Text; 
        } 

        if (slcGender.SelectedItem.Value == "") { 
            genVal = slcGender.SelectedItem.Value; 
            gVal = "Any Gender"; 
        } 
        if (slcGender.SelectedItem.Value != "") { 
            genVal = theGender.Substring(0, 1); 
            gVal = slcGender.SelectedItem.Text; 
        } 

        sqlCode = "SELECT * FROM [HERE]"; --example query

        /* EXECUTE AND DISPLAY THE DATA IN THE ASP PAGE */ 


        using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlCode, Conn)) { 
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) { 
                if (reader.HasRows) { 
                    rptContent.DataSource = reader; 
                    rptContent.DataBind(); 
                } 
                if (!reader.HasRows) { 
                    dlo.InnerHtml = "NO RESULT"; 
                } 
                int count = rptContent.Items.Count; 
                dlo.InnerHtml = "Your search in " + lVal + " by " + sVal + " and " + gVal + " returned "+count+" matches"; 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

I have a label in my ASPX page:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="dispSearch" style="float: left;"></asp:Label>
```

How can I display a "Searching... Please wait" message to the label above while the search is executing and display "Search is complete" message once it's done?

My UpdatePanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="TaskUpdateProgress" runat="server" DynamicLayout="False" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel2" DisplayAfter="0">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <asp:Image ImageUrl="theImages/loadanim_ff.gif" Width="319px" Height="3px" runat="server" ID="TaskLoadingImage"/>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
            <div style="width: 100%; color: #000000; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;" ID="dlo" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></div>
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptContent">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table border="0" ID="tblInfo" style="background: #43A79A; width: 100%;" ClientIDMode="Static">
                <tr>
                    <td>Physician Name</td>
                    <td>Image</td>
                    <td>Gender</td>
                    <td>Office1</td>
                    <td>Office2</td>
                    <td>Office3</td>
                    <td>Office4</td>
                </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%# Eval("Physician Name").ToString() %></td>
                <td><img src="http://wp.com/<%# Eval("Image").ToString() %>" /></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Gender").ToString() %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Office1").ToString() %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Office2").ToString() %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Office3").ToString() %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Office4").ToString() %></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnGoAll" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common approach is to use [UpdateProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398821%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) control. It's specifically designed to be used with UpdatePanel to display progress to the user during partial postbacks.

Comment: I have to use a separate updatepanel? I don't want the displayprogress the same location where the result will show up.

Comment: No. Not separate update panel. An `UpdateProgress` control for your UpdatePanel. You're free to put any HTML elements inside of it you like - including your styled label. UpdateProgress is invisible by default and appears only after postback is happening for some designated time (default 500ms, but this is configurable). So just add UpdateProgrss to your form, place your label there - and see what happens (and see the link to reference in my answer for more examples)

Comment: Maybe the search is going fast but nothing is displayed while it's searching :/

Comment: Is it taking less than a second? Can u simulate slowdown then by adding something like `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);` to your search code?

Comment: much less than a second. Where should I add that line? between what?

Comment: It took little longer but I did not see the loading image

Comment: Don't place UpdateProgress *inside* of UpdatePanel - it has to be *outside* on its own

Comment: Updated it and it is still not displaying anything

Comment: Cool :) Just curious why it didn't before. In any case, glad the solution was helpful

Comment: Silly reason... The image URL wasn't correct and text was in white so I couldn't see it. Thanks again :)